# Run 2 commands in the same line in terminal emulator

Tags: terminal

I want to execute two commands in the same line on Android terminal emulator.

> Example: the two commands `svc wifi disable` and `exit

I want to create a widget to disable the WLAN and out of the terminal emulator app at the same time, and in the terminal emulator app widget, I can only put one command.

[image: widget entry]

Comment: `svc wifi disable && exit`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute each command only if the previous one succeeded, then combine them using the `&&` operator:

Your code should be as follows:

```
svc wifi disable && exit
```

It will work only if your  first command successfully  execute.

Answer (score 2):

Like Andrew correctly said, with && you can combine them but you also can just add more than one command by ending each command by a ";", e.g. put into the arguments field (leave empty the command field):

```
svc wifi disable; exit
```