# How to automate command line when specific application is launched?

Tags: terminal

So basically I want to run a few line of code each time a specific application is launched and closed.

Is there application which could do that ? (Busybox ?)

I actually have to print it my self in a terminal emulator and it's a bit harsh :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) and [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), an automation app

Create a macro in which the *Trigger* is launch application of your choice and action is *Launch Shortcut* where you choose *Term Shortcut* and key in the commands in the *arguments* . See [Firelord's answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113982/) for additional details [Home screen icon for terminal program?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42801/131553)

- To understand how MacroDroid works and required **settings**,  my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133394/131553)
- See this to enter multiple commands [Run 2 commands in the same line in terminal emulator](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/154431)  ( since you mentioned you have a *few* lines of code not a single command )

Comment: Great answer but it seems not to work with`su` (application block when I want to add other lines, any advice ?)

Comment: Thanks. It works for [me as shown here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/127286/131553). Though i used a single command. Can you please recheck your syntax and try with `su-c`

Comment: Another thing you can try is split your commands into easier to troubleshoot sections and add each of this section as an action (you can hand multiple actions for a trigger). If you want you can separate these actions by *wait X sec*. Note that if you are using `&&` to join command unless the first command is executed the next will not run. Breaking into sections and multiple actions can help troubleshoot