# Sync to Desktop then automatically delete local/original files

Tags: applications, sync, cloud

I'm looking for something to transfer files and then **automatically** delete the original files. The situation that I'm planning is to take pictures in my phone, then when I'm in my house or in a local wifi, sync them to my notebook/desktop, delete the original in the phone and then from the copy from my notebook/desktop, upload it to Google Drive, I'm aware that there are other tools that can achieve this manually but what I haven't been able to find is something that can make this process automatically/seamlessly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @beeshyams Great, I'd be using both Windows and Linux so that fits perfectly, would you link me to a good implementation of rsync in Android? most stuff in the Playstore seems very old. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/164437/131553) but it requires root to run rsync on Android. See also the link in answer which links to rsync for both platforms ( I don't think that requires root). There is a nifty utility called *Grsync* for Linux which i use to manually backup my external SD card. Don't know enough Linux to automate it

Comment: @beeshyams No, I don't think so, and even if then, I have root permissions in my devices, thank you so much for your comments, this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @beeshyams Yes, I'm going to write an answer when I set it up completely so others can benefit from this, since I couldn't find anything from just googling.

Answer (score 3):

Google Photos is a free app that periodically offers to "free up space" on your device by uploading your photos to photos.google.com (at the quality you choose) and then deleting them from your device.

Items uploaded via Google Photos don't use your Google Drive's limited storage if they're stored in "High quality" but they do if they're stored in "Original quality" (higher quality than high quality).

In order to sync to your PC:
In Google Photos, enable the "Google Drive" setting. 
In Google Drive, check the "Automatically put your Google Photos into a folder in My Drive" setting. (You should see a Google Photos folder in Drive then.)

Then, sync it to your PC with the Google Drive sync desktop program. (There's a link to download it at the bottom left of the Google Drive website. Sign in and select the folder/s to sync.)

Photos added to Google Photos will show up in that folder and sync to your PC, and any photos you add to this folder on your PC will sync to the website.

Comment: @beeshyams OP's question just talks about "taking pictures and sync them, then delete them from device, and have them sync'd with GDrive". So what's wrong with the result here? They get sync'd to GDrive (or what does Photos use as backend?) and deleted from the device, and OP can then sync them to the PC. Same result.

Comment: @beeshyams subtleties :) As you confirm, I countered your down-vote with an upvote :) Ping me for comment cleanup once you're clear with Melissa (who might need the context). // **Melissa:** could you please include the second part of the requirement, i.e. how to get those photos to the desktop machine then? And does Google Photos use Google Drive, as OP demanded?

Comment: @beeshyams Sorry for the delay, thanks for the vigilance and the suggestion!

Comment: No problem. There you go with an upvote from me