# Sync files to the cloud, but only upload differential changes?

Tags: sync, files, dropbox

I want to maintain a large file synced between my android device and a PC. I will be doing small changes to this file file all the time on the device, and I want these changes to be reflected on the PC. Ideally the file should *not* be uploaded in full everytime it changes (because it is so big), but only the `differential` changes (which are small). Is there a tool  / app that does this? Does Dropbox / Dropsync work like this?

**Update:** This says that Dropbox only uploads the [differential part](https://www.dropbox.com/help/syncing-uploads/upload-entire-file). But I do not know if the same applies to Dropsync.

Comment: @beeshyams Before I consider `rsync` (which I suppose will take more config to do), I would like to know if Dropbox for Android has differential sync, at least for some  file types? I am thinking of PDFs, and the kind of change I make on the tablet that should get synced is annotations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62658/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-becko).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differential sync or Delta sync is a feature that is available only on the PC version and **not** on Android as explained in Dropbox help pages [Delta sync for Android](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Syncing-and-uploads/Delta-sync-for-Android/td-p/105654)

> **Power:**....Delta sync means you have to carry out hashing operations on the file, which on pretty much all mobile devices is a **non-power optimised** operation....
>
> **Hashing Overheads for small files:** Now, if the file is very large, and the change set is very small, sure there will be a tipping point, but for mobile stuff we aren't talking about a usage pattern which generally covers files hundreds of MB upward in size being edited, its going to be **brand new files** (photos, videos etc) or **small changes to documents** etc....You aren't going to be editing huge videos on an Android phone or tablets for example.

(Emphasis Supplied)

- If Dropbox for Android doesn't do Delta Sync, Dropsync logically cannot do, since it feeds Dropbox. Besides, app forum talks of *comparing files* but not differential or Delta sync
- I couldn't find any alternative cloud solutions that implement this sync on Android, perhaps for the reason mentioned earlier. Even services like *Own Cloud* which have an Android app, give [similar reasons](https://dragotin.wordpress.com/2015/02/09/incremental-sync-in-owncloud/)
- Only alternative I can think of is using `rsync` which does **incremental backups**, which is *faster* than differential backup (See a nice tabulated summary [here](http://www.backup.info/difference-between-full-differential-and-incremental-backup))

  Some pointers that may help you implement this solution ( should you decide on this route, it may help to ask a separate question for details )

  - How it is implemented for USB backup. [Sync ext SD to USB OTG **without** using a PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/164437/131553)
    See footnotes of Izzy's answer for app based solution using *rsync for Android* and where to download it from
  - From SE.ubuntu , [How to rsync to Android](https://askubuntu.com/q/343502)

Comment: Thanks for a very thorough answer. I will consider `rsync`, and post another question if needed.

Comment: Xodo PDF reader claims to have this feature (for PDFs only): `"For Dropbox, data use is minimized by uploading only the changes you make, not the whole document"`. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xodo.pdf.reader&hl=en_GB. I am testing it myself, anyone has experience with this?

Comment: Giving that this feature *seems* to exist for PDFs, I am setting up a dedicated thread for this format only, here: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/180263/6813.