# Installing rsync on Android to transfer files from Android to OSX

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am trying to use `rsync` to transfer some files from my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy S10+ / Android V10) to my local machine (OSX / Mojave).

I did the following:

1. Installed [SSH/SFTP server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.sshserver&hl=en) on my Android device and started the server
2. Verified that I am able to `ssh` into the phone (although it logs me in as user `u0_a312` and not `my_user`?)

```
$ ssh my_user@192.168.0.16 -p 2222

The authenticity of host '[192.168.0.16]:2222 ([192.168.0.16]:2222)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:3mNL574rJyHCOGm1e7Upx4NHXMg/YnJJzq+jXhdQQxI.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[192.168.0.16]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password authentication
Password:
:/ $ whoami
u0_a312
```

3. Attempted to run `rsync` from my local OSX machine to copy remote Android files to my laptop

```
rsync -avzhP -e "ssh -p 2222" my_user@192.168.0.16:/storage/6632-6330/DCIM/Camera/* .

Password authentication
Password:
exec request failed on channel 0
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/io.c(453) [receiver=2.6.9]
```

As you can see, I ran into an error on step 3. From some basic snooping on forums, it seems like `rsync` needs to be installed on the Android remote device.

(That's also backed up by the fact that `which rsync` returns nothing when executed from the Android shell)

However:

- How do I go about installing `rsync` on the phone? Is this even the right solution here?
- I never needed to do this on my previous phone (Galaxy S7), the above `rsync` process "just worked". Did something change with the standard installation of Android with regards to `rsync` ?

Comment: I've never tried that, but maybe [Syncopoli](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.amoradi.syncopoli/) could help. It describes itself as "An rsync client that works", so it hopefully, erm, works.

Comment: Obviously you need `rsync` binary on Android side for syncing to work. `rsync` has never been a part of standard Android installation. // You can use Termux for both `sshd` and `rsync`. Simple. Or put `rsync` binary somewhere on your $PATH. // Another idea is to use `rclone` on both sides with `sftp` built-in server. // Why you log in as user `u0_a312` (the app's UID) and not `my_user`, the concept of users and login in Android: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209918

Comment: Answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/179893/131553) well help on how to install

Comment: Answer here may be of some interest https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179899/131553

Comment: Hi @user2490003 everything you are doing is right and the reason its not working is SSH/SFTP server does not support rsync. Just use the app called SimpleSSHD from playstore and it will work with your existing commands..Only pain is there's a little extra work to do and that is you need to copy the id_rsa.pub file to the apps authorised_keys folder for passwordless authentication.

Answer (score 2):

First on Android each app has an own user-id/account, hence `u0_a312`is the user of the app that runs the ssh server. Regular Linux user accounts like `myuser` don't exist on Android.

Based on the path `/storage/6632-6330/` I would assume that you are trying to access the external sd-card.

On a non-rooted device write access to ext-sd is not possible on Android using standard Linux/Unix file programs (this is only possible via Android Java API). Only if the ssh/ftp server + rsync was specially adopted to use this API it can work.

On Android 10/11 the situation is even getting worse because of the new ["Scoped storage"](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) system. Not sure if it is still possible to get full access to all files on the external ad-card.