# control charging for Samsung Galaxy S3 that is in charger 24/7

Tags: samsung, charging

I have Samsung Galaxy S3 in the charger 24/7, so it's not good for battery. How can I set charging so that the phone spends battery to say 30% before charging it to full?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575). I've rephrased your post slightly so it is on-topic and still meets your intention.

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167260/automatically-limit-stop-battery-charging-at-a-given-percentage for the same problem on a different phone

Comment: @DanHulme: thanks. The problem posed by OP is slightly different- one he wants a cut off at lower level of discharging (instead of charging) and two Samsung peculiarities, which you are well aware of. Posted an answer that may help OP

Answer (score 0):

If your device is not rooted, it's not possible

If it's rooted, it's possible but you have to get your hands dirty, since ways below target to cut off battery charging at upper limit and not while discharging to a lower limit , as you want

- [[APP][ROOT][4.4+]Battery Charge Limit v1.0.1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=73053787&postcount=806)  available free at XDA works for your device as can be seen from linked user post. You can download the app from [here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=file-thanks&fid=889764386195919111&mid=99&download_id=rtqc27bgtj20e7522b1dadsls1&tid=1502267020&hc=1cf246b5a85efdcc984052ac5596aeeca9a1f52cb2ddebb66e51283744d30fc6). Fortunately, this is open source so you can tinker with it
- Have a look at this for trying other ways of achieving your goal [Automatically limit (stop) battery charging at a given percentage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167260/131553) . Here again, the actions of discontinue charging can be configured to lower limit