# Shell: get battery voltage_now if power were not connected

Tags: battery, charging

I am trying to make my device stop charging (`echo 0 > /sys/class/power_supply/battery/charging_enabled`, the easy part) when the battery's voltage reaches [3920000 µV](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries).

Using `cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/voltage_now` or `dumpsys battery`, I can also tell that the battery is at a certain voltage, like `3916000` (in µV). When the device is not charging, this number is the battery's charge voltage, the number I want. However, when the device is connected to a charger (DC out is normally 5V), this value is neither the battery's voltage, nor the input voltage, but some value in between, because of how charging works.

Because the `voltage_now` does not reflect the battery's rest voltage when charging, and this number is dependent on which charger I use, I cannot obtain the number I need (`3920000`) whenever the device should stop charging. So apart from pulse charging and sampling, how should I get the battery's non-charging voltage from the shell while charging?

---

Note: "manually calculating the battery percentage when the voltage is 3.92V, and then stopping charging when `/sys/class/power_supply/battery/capacity` reaches that number" is not a satisfactory answer or workaround.

Comment: I don't know if voltage can be read and not sure that is a reliable way of doing it (what if the battery ages and cannot reach full voltage on full charge?). Alternate method to do that is mentioned in my answer here https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167260/131553

Comment: The voltage *is* reported by `voltage_now` and it is the battery's current voltage as advertised, but I want the "rest voltage" of the battery if the cable were unplugged at that instant. The rest of the task involving `charging_enabled` is already implemented the same way as your previous answer.

Comment: You may like to look at the Magisk module used in this answer. But the kernel needs to support this https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223812/131553