# Don't charge the battery but use connected power to run the phone

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, oneplus-7

Answers to this question [Is power consumed from battery to run the phone when charging?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/130000/131553) explain how charging while phone is in use does both - charging the battery **and** powering the on going activities.

My question is different — **Can I stop charging the battery but use the connected power for ongoing activities?**

*Why do I want to do this?*

- I want to charge the battery within ideal limits (see [Ideal charging / discharging percentage for maximum battery life?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/156526/131553))

and

- at the same time use the charging power to keep running the phone without any heat stress on battery, thus extending battery life.
- Also the battery is not drained, enabling me to use the phone for longer time without charging

Edit : I am not looking for dedicated cables or hardware that can possibly do this

Comment: Note that no matter what the UI says, in general case the charger does not have enough power to meet the peak phone demands. That's why most phones and tablets (and also some laptops) cannot be started without a battery. Depending on how you acheive your "battery idle" state, you will either get quick discharge-charge-idle transitions (defeating the initial idea), or slowly depleting battery.

Comment: @fraxinus 1.As mentioned in the answer the effective power supplied to run the phone is that of USB 2. *quick discharge-charge-idle transitions* do not happen in this implementation. I have run the device for 4 hours max in this condition with **only one** percent drop (watching you tube) - this point is also briefly mentioned in the answer

Comment: This has always been possible AFAIK using a Factory Cable.  You can either make a Factory Cable from an existing USB cable, or buy a Factory Cable Adapter that does the same _(Team Blackhat used to sell the adapters, but I don't believe they still do)_.  A Factory Cable, or Factory Cable Adapter, supplies power to the device, entirely bypassing the battery

Comment: @JW0914. I have read of such cables but they won't meet the requirements of bullet point 1 in the question isn't it? That is of charging till user wants to. Perhaps you are referring to the title and mailing this observation, in which case I agree title is misleading, sorry, didn't frame that well in an effort to keep it short. Thanks for your observations

Comment: @beeshyams I was only pointing out that a hardware solution exists to the overarching question of "can you run a smartphone solely off USB power", which is inline with bullet #1 if the battery is already at/near 80% charged. If wanting a solution that does both, the most practical way is a software-based solution, like that in your answer, else you'd need to either manually re-arrange the pinout of the Factory Cable, such as by using molex/bullet/spade connectors, or have some mechanism for doing so electronically, such as a switch (either is what a non-rooted device would likely have to use).

Comment: @JW0914 Point taken though it would be inconvenient to switch cables just for this. Just to make sure that cable /hardware is not what I am looking for, added that bit to the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I asked a similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1365704/can-phones-tablets-avoid-charging-from-usb-power

Comment: OP, or @JW0914 Where can I read more about such a "Factory Cable Adapter"? Is it an industry wide standard? How does it work? Does anyone still make them? Do for example modern Samsung phones support this trick? 

ACC app's "battery idle mode" is not supported by samsung kernels it seems, that much I know.

Comment: @Spectraljump A factory cable or adapter _(some refer to it as a fastboot factory cable)_ provides power directly to the phone's USB port to allow the phone to boot without a battery or with a dead battery. I'm unsure where you can buy one, but they're easy to make with an existing micro-USB cable _(it destroys the cable for other uses)_ and guides can be found via google, although I'm unsure if they work on USB-C devices. The model of phone generally doesn't matter, as most use the same USB pin-out

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if your device is rooted running [Advanced Charging Controller-Acc](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-magic-charging-switch-cs-v2017-9-t3668427) Magisk module
*and* device kernel supports (see currently known list at the end of answer. For more join [telegram](https://t.me/vr25_xda)
)

- Battery Idle Mode: To activate this feature at a user defined battery level.

And/Or

- Custom Charging Voltage Limits: Activates this feature at a user defined voltage level. This method is superior to first method since granular voltage control is possible  Keep in mind that battery charge level is *not* an accurate indication of voltage. Kernels that support this, include support for first mode too.

First step is to configure charging to be stopped at a safe level, in my case, 75%, using the Acc module

Next step is to use the charging power to run the phone *only*

**How does it work?**

In either methods (battery idle mode or Voltage based) , the charger is fooled into "believing" temperature conditions aren't good for charging (either the reported battery temperature is too high or too low, so battery charging is discontinued as a safety precaution).

That means the device is drawing power from the external power supply alone - which is exactly what we wanted! And the battery doesn't get drained because it is not being used (of course over a long period of time it would drop a percentage point. As an example I used the device to surf for 4 hours, mostly YouTube videos and lost  *just 1%* of battery)

On my OnePlus 7, battery idle mode is supported by [Kirisakura kernel](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-7-pro/development/kernel-kirisakura-1-0-0-op7-pro-aka-t3933916). Interestingly, beta versions of stock ROM have this feature in stock kernel but one doesn't know if it makes it to next stable version (Edit : Stock kernel on 10.3.2 supports idle battery mode as verified by me)

When this feature is running, a low USB  equivalent power is fed to the phone and conventional charging indicators show charging with zero power. Note that the second screenshot (Ampere app) shows "not charging" and no word about discharging, so the battery is at status quo. Normally, such apps show a binary status, either charging or discharging. Here, you see the difference

[image]

[image]

This screenshot below is from ACCA (Acc App, optional companion app of Acc magisk module ) which offers all the command line options (believe me, a ton of them) in a user friendly GUI. It shows battery charging idle mode at 75%

[image]

---

**Support Battery Idle Mode**

- Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1
- Essential Phone
- Lenovo K5 Pro L38041 (kunlun)
- Motorola Moto G4 Play
- OnePlus 7/Pro
- Xiaomi Redmi 3 (ido)
- Xiami Redmi Note 8
- Pixel 4a on Android 11 (not initially but in subsequent updates) and Android 12.

**Support Custom Max Charging Voltage**

- Essential Phone
- Lenovo K5 Pro L38041 (kunlun)
- Xiami Redmi Note 8
  ...

Comment: Note : The Magisk module is being continuously being developed, so it's best to use the XDA thread or the Telegram channel

Comment: According to the xda thread (and based on lack of dev activity since nov 2020) it seems the project is dead, and indeed the client app at least seems to be buggy on new devices.

I don't know of any alternatives that prioritize bypassed cable power over battery, and would gladly buy a "Factory Cable Adapter" but I can't find anything on either fronts.

Comment: @Spectraljump development has re-started a few months ago

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I  want to add my solution. I have been using a tablet as a control panel for home automation. The first one died, with a swollen battery that made the screen detach from the case.

Samsung repaired it, but didn't tell me the cause. I  realised it later. So I  now use the home automation to disconnect power to it for 4 hours a day.

A simpler soltion would be put a mechanical or electronic timer to do the same.