# How to install Advanced Charging Controller (acc) module?

Tags: battery-life, magisk

I have a phone that's been rooted using `Magisk`. How to install something like the [acc](https://github.com/VR-25/acc/) module? The [instructions](https://github.com/VR-25/acc/#quick-start-guide) state running `acc` commands, but where from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using this for several years now and it's a great app for your battery.

**Installation**

- It's a Magisk module. Install it like any other Magisk module and it's better to reboot though not always required for this module.
- You can get the latest version and help from [Telegram group](https://t.me/vr25_xda). The telegram group is very active, with the developer often answering questions.
- Forget about the front end app mentioned in Github notes. Those apps are outdated.

**Commands**

- Use  Termux (not the Play Store version which again is very outdated) . Get it from [Github or F-Droid](https://termux.dev/en/). You can use any other terminal emulator of your choice.
- You need to use `su` before running the commands
- Documentation:

  - `acc -r g`: Full (HTML)
  - `acc -h g`: Condensed (plain text)
- Some simple commands:

  - `acc: Wizard` : gives you an interface to get started.
  - acc pause resume: Set pause and resume % (e.g., `acc 80 70`), defaults are 75 70.
  - acc -s mcc=milliamps: Set charging current limit (no value means default)
  - acc -s mcc=millivolts: Set charging voltage limit (no value means default)
  - acc -f: Charge once to 100% without restrictions.

I mainly use it for *idle charging* (see [Don't charge the battery but use connected power to run the phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223812/131553)). Also, I configured the voltage supplied to the battery to be low enough not to cause heating, which is a well reported problem with Pixel 6 series (thankfully, it's alleviated on Android 14).

Comment: >  "It's a Magisk module".

It is, but github documents installation methods besides that as well. Including terminal-based ones.

Comment: Yes, I was keeping it simple and the way most use it. One can build it too I think but the end result whichever way you do, is that it appears as a Magisk module. Hence, the mention of it as a Magisk module//The amount of customization one can do in a single terminal command is mind boggling for me

Comment: Also a word of caution. ACCA is a front end spp by a different developer that initially was in use but now very outdated. Yet, you will find commands like `acca -sp`which are valid and not to be associated with front end  ACCA. There are variants of ACCA too but sadly haven't kept pace and hence crippled. Using the terminal is the best way

Comment: Cheers, will stick to the CLI.