# Can I force Pixel 6 Pro to slow charge?

Tags: charging, battery-life, google-pixel-6, battery-saver

There are long periods of time when I know I will stay in place so I would like to be able to connect the phone to the charger and have it charge slowly to try and curb issues created with fast charging.

Preferably it would be something that I would be able to quickly switch to fast charging when needed.

Phone is not rooted, but I'm willing to root it if need be. I already use adaptive charging during the night. I was hoping for something not linked to the alarm.

Comment: If you are ready to root , see [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/254202/131553)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be possible just using hardware - if you use a 5V/1A (5W) charging block, for instance, your phone would charge at a maximum of 5W, which is rather slow for today's charging standards. That being said, even a 5W charger will charge your phone within several hours.

Another option, again hardware-based and assuming you're somewhere where it would be practical, is the [Pixel Stand 2](https://store.google.com/us/product/pixel_stand_2nd_gen?hl=en-US), which allows you to choose "Max charge" or "Charge quietly," which is effectively equivalent to "slower." These can be switched at any time, and wireless charging for the Pixel phones is generally slower than wired regardless.

These being possible, Pixel phones already offer [several built-in and features that can be enabled](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/6090612?hl=en&sjid=5966587067923905993-NC#zippy=%2Chow-to-use-adaptive-charging-pixel-and-later%2Coptimising-for-battery-health-pixel-and-later%2Ccharge-as-much-or-as-little-as-needed%2Cprotecting-your-battery-pixel-later-including-fold) that make this not as necessary as it used to be. See especially the "Protecting your battery" section linked.