# Restart charge from powerbank on rootet phone

Tags: usb, battery, charging, battery-life

A have rooted android 4.3 device and charge it from power bank. Charging stop after 100% and not continue after phone discharged until i unplug and plug again usb connector or push butoon on powerbank.

How to restart charge process programmicaly on rooted phone?

Powerbank: Xiaomi Mi Power Bank 2C 
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S III GT-I9300
Android: 4.3

Comment: You can try the first option (maybe others too) from my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/195506/131553)

Comment: It enables charging to be commence at a user chosen level. Don't know if it works on your Android version