# Change battery meter behavior

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, calibration

I heard that charging li-ion batteries to less voltage value *heavily* increases number of (charge-discharge) cycles, while decreasing phone work time(energy return from charge) only for *a little*.

[image]

Charging only a half of capacity increases number of charges 3x, so there is 1.5x outcome in energy that i could get from battery for its life. I have 5000 mAh battery, and a huge power bank. It is very big capacity, and i am ready to sacrifice some working time to prolong battery life for years as much as possible.

So for now it could charge to 4.2V to 100%, and i want to "reconfigure" or "recalibrate" BMS. It should "think" for example that 3.9V is 100% charge and stop charging it, and 3.6V is a 0% and is a device shutdown voltage.

How to set this in Android?

Comment: Graph appears to be from Battery University (from memory). In any case it doesn't hurt, rather it is recommended to link the source

Comment: @beeshyams https://energymag.net/dod-depth-of-discharge/

Comment: Thanks. But the graph is for Nickel-Iron. Android devices use Li-ion or Li-Po so the values may be wrong for this discussion (while the trend is similar) . See [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com) and sources quoted in the linked answers (the last one)

Comment: That's not the right chart for what you're doing — that's a chart for if you charged after discharging your phone to 50% instead of 0%. Limiting the voltage the battery is charged to is much more effective; your increase for charging to 3.9V is ≈8x. See https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries for details.

Comment: @derobert, I want to set 3.9V as 100% of battery instead of 4.3V to not ruin it! But i haven't rooted my phone yet, this seems ti be required to set upper limit.

Comment: @xakepp35 yeah, I understand. I was just pointing out it doesn't give you 3× the cycles, it's more like 8×. I don't think you can do it without root or using e.g., a smart plug to turn off the charger.

Comment: @derobert I thilk its like water tank. If you pump in too much tank explodes, if you pump out too much air pressure could collapse it, in both ways it would be wrecked. I think that 4.35V is too much for my phone, it is stated like that at 100%. I just wondered how they assumed to fix that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters your device needs to be rooted ( see [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting) )

One way could be to fool the system by pretending you have a smaller mAh capacity battery so that it stops charging prematurely (relative to actual capacity) but that's tough because the battery capacity files are hard coded into the kernel, so you need to "cook" your kernel. See
 [Where are the battery capacity files located?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145263/131553)

Practical alternative is to stop charging at a level that matches your desired voltage.

- You can do it the hard way. See
  [Automatically limit (stop) battery charging at a given percentage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167260/131553)

Or

- Easier way. See [How to limit charging to 60%](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195502/131553)

Also see [Ideal charging / discharging percentage for maximum battery life?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/156526/131553)

Rather than actually figuring out the voltage levels at which you want to charge / shutdown , it is easier to go by battery charged level and stop charging

Comment: They took good and greatly tunable linux and.. closed, closed, closed it! They are closing bootloaders, not exposing vital settings.. I cannot even set MENU background colors to black, its blinding white background with black text scheme, despite the fact that "information is light" and its "absence is dark" (background)! I even start wishing android alternative to be developed, because i like it less and less, with every newer version, since android 4 :(