# Is there a way to configure always-plugged-in android devices to partially change battery or NOT stay fully charged?

Tags: battery, charging

So I’ll apologize in advance as I’m an iPhone user for mobile and Linux for work/desktop - Android is mostly unfamiliar territory to me.  I’ve recently set up 3 or 4 android devices (a various combination of older tablets and phones from different manufacturers) as more or less “display boards”.  After one of them quit working and I took it apart to find a badly swollen battery pouch I realized that these devices spend 99.9% of their time plugged into USB power, and as such they’ve spent their entire lives at or near 100% charge, which we know is not great for these types of batteries.

Is there some way in the OS (or otherwise, I suppose) to configure these devices in “always plugged in mode” so that the batteries stay within a friendlier range for state-of-charge?  I don’t remember details but I think the recommendation is that Li-ion batteries be left at/near 50% if they’re not being cycled.

Neither my coding chops nor my motivation are sufficient to go poking around on my own in the android development world, but it seems like this might be a common enough use case that there might be a setting buried somewhere that would do this?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have existing Q&A for this topic: [How to limit charging to a user defined limit?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/195502/44325), [Automatically limit (stop) battery charging at a given percentage](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167260/44325), [Don't charge the battery but use connected power to run the phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223812/44325)

Comment: As for "some way in the OS", please note that due to the vast customization of Android OS, it's not a standard feature. I know [Samsung has one](https://www.sammobile.com/news/protect-galaxy-smartphone-battery-for-longer-lifespan-guide/) and Google Pixel has none, but I can't say for other manufacturers.

Comment: Having a root is must unless you use external charge limiters for solutions in first comment. I have been using ACC for years now

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use a mechanical or electronic timer to switch off power to the devices for a set number of hours.  I am doing precisely this for my wall-mount Android tablet with home automation.