# Android control battery charge programmatically

Tags: battery, charging

I'am using a Linage Android image (rooted) to control the battery charge and discharge with the commands:

Charge:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_slate_mode
```

Stop charging:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_slate_mode
```

The problem that after sending the command to charge, the charge type changes from "AC charge" to "USB Charge" and the current level drop to less than 500mA. I am connected AC power outlet.
If I disconnect and connect again the power outlet the current goes to 1A.

Reading the following article bellow some devices are a file to change the voltage (/sys/class/power_supply/battery/voltage_max), but mine doesn't have.

https://www.androidpit.com/forum/770904/root-battery-life-improve-battery-life-by-reducing-the-charge-termination-voltage

The picture show the files that I have on the folder:
[image: ls /sys/class/power_supply/battery/]

Samsung Tab E 7.0 SM-T113NU

Android 7.0.1 - Linage 14.1

App and ADB rooted

Best regards,

Comment: I would suggest you to try the Magisk module mentioned in answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/223813/131553), it's far easier than trying to figure it out yourself. `Slate_mode` is messy in the sense it doesn't seem to work as expected always//If you are keen to do it your way only, this [answer may help](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/167626/131553)

Comment: Hi,

I'm using the ACC Magisk as recommeded. The problem persist. Even i connect to the power outlet it appears "USB Powered" with slow charge. I've tried change the current and voltage but doesn't work either.


dumpsys battery
  AC powered: false
  USB powered: true
  Wireless powered: false
  Max charging current: 0
  Max charging voltage: 0
  Charge counter: 0
  status: 2
  health: 2
  present: true
  level: 86
  scale: 100
  voltage: 4100
  temperature: 320
  technology: Li-ion

Comment: Go to ACC app forum on XDA and search for the Telegram group. Post your details in Telegram to get a quicker reply from developer. Samsung does some funny stuff and he can answer best